# Recursive "Anaconda-Navigator" would like to access your folder on mac OS Catalina

Tags: anaconda, spyder, macos-catalina

I have extensively looked over for all solutions available on the Mac OS Catalina permission issue with Anaconda. I did every alternative I found, including deleting all anaconda related files and reinstalling them, still, my issue remains.

I am able to run my code without major issues, but there is a recurring pop-up screen that opens every time spyder saves or run a file. The screen is the one below:

[image]

I tried to add Anaconda-Navigator as a full disk access application on Systems Preference> Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access. If I don't close Spyder, it runs without the pop-ups but if I restart Anaconda the issue is back and Anaconda-Navigator does not have full disk access anymore.

I feel quite dumb not figuring this out and I imagine something simple is the solution. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try starting Spyder from terminal:

`~/anaconda3/bin/spyder`

None of the other solutions worked for me but this seemed to have solved the problem.

I suspect it is due to stricter security on Catalina OS, as others have similar permission issues, see [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11387) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372768/file-permissions-issue-with-python-spyder-anaconda-after-upgrading-mac-to-catali).
Launching Spyder from terminal seems to get around this problem.

Comment: added benefit is you can now open spyder without running Anaconda first.  shortcut: add this command as an alias to your .bash_profile or .zprofile file.  e.g. alias spyder="/path1/path2/anaconda3/bin/spyder &" to run it in background

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no simple solution to that. The Anaconda team suggest to reinstall everything paying attentino to set the installation folder as a subfolder of your home folder (the problem is related to a relocation of the Anaconda folder due to the os upgrade). 
Alternatively, they also provide a patch that you can try to run if don't want to reinstall everything. 
Here's the link:
[How to Restore Anaconda after Update to MacOS Catalina](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well when I opened Jupyter Lab from the GUI, but if I shut down Navigator and started it from the command line, I no longer had the recursive permission request problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just start Anaconda Navigator from terminal. Run this in terminal:

`anaconda-navigator`

Comment: This seems it is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, then fixed it by going to `System Preferences -> Privacy and Security -> Full Disk Access` and allowing Anaconda. No other solutions would permanently work for me.