# Updated to Mac OS Catalina, Spyder 3 errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, macos-catalina

I've been using High Sierra and was finally able to switch to Catalina. Now I'm having a LOT of problems with Anaconda/Spyder.

1) It takes about five tries to get Spyder to open. I get an error that it crashed on a previous attempt. I've reset it according to the directions and also reinstalled it. Hasn't helped.

2) Once it does open, I can't access a CSV file on a SD card. It's a data file from a different computer. It has a permission error. After a lot of searching, I found how to see the "owner" of the file. It's me. Numbers will open it without any problems.

3) I tried moving the file to the desktop. When it tries to create a results file, I get "File can't be found." The file was to be created by the program.

path = ("/Volumes/WXDATA/")

fileWrite = (path + "Results-WX.csv")

f = open(fileWrite,'a+')

This program was working good till the upgrade. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372768/file-permissions-issue-with-python-spyder-anaconda-after-upgrading-mac-to-catali) and its corresponding answers. They could help you too.

Comment: Thank you. I hope Anaconda/Spyder gets fixed soon.

Comment: This is a macOS problem, not an Anaconda one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with Anaconda under an upgrade to Catalina. [This post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) talks about what changed in MacOS Catalina and how to fix it.

The main suggestion is to reinstall Anaconda (or miniconda) into a path in your home folder.

If you want to keep your conda environments exactly as they currently are, you can follow the official conda [instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) on how to build an identical environment to one you already have.

Comment: I've installed and uninstalled multiple times in multiple directories. Same problem. I think I did come up with a solution. So far Pycharm is working and I'm learning how to use it instead of Anaconda/Spyder. Hopefully the Anaconda problem will be fixed and I can go back to it. Thank you very much with the help!