# MacOS: "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" when trying to import modules in Spyder

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, spyder

When importing modules in the python terminals, for example

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-d66304f7d0f7>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.integrate import odeint

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from ._bvp import solve_bvp

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import OptimizeResult

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", line 391, in <module>
    from ._minimize import *

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .equality_constrained_sqp import equality_constrained_sqp

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/equality_constrained_sqp.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .projections import projections

  File "/Users/henrypalasciano/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/projections.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky_AAt

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1249, in _get_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1213, in _path_importer_cache

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

The only way I have been able to resolve this so far in uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda and reopening Spyder. This error returns after closing and reopening Spyder.
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow! As what user did you install anaconda? `henrypalasciano` or did you perhaps install it using `sudo`?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like another case of the `PermissionError` problem introduced by macOS Catalina. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372768/file-permissions-issue-with-python-spyder-anaconda-after-upgrading-mac-to-catali) to learn how to fix it.

Comment: I installed it using henrypalasciano as user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File permissions issue with python/Spyder/Anaconda after upgrading mac to Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372768/file-permissions-issue-with-python-spyder-anaconda-after-upgrading-mac-to-catali)